# Why are include-like declaration generally preferred, but profile classes should not use them to declare component classes?

Tags: puppet

- What are the reasons for these different recommendations in the case of profiles declaring component classes?

I am specifically asking this because I have seen some codebase that tends to apply the recommendation of using include-like style, even when profiles declares component classes. So it feels like they are not following the roles and profiles recommendations, but still sticking to Puppet's general guidelines.

- Also, are there any other similar cases when resource-like declarations should be preferred?

---

The main documentation page for classes seems to strongly encourage usage of include-like declaration over resource-like declarations, and states the following

> Include-like declarations are the most common; they are flexible and
>   idempotent, so you can safely repeat them without causing errors.
>   Resource-like declarations are mostly useful if you want to pass
>   parameters to the class but can't or don't use Hiera.

And also:

> CAUTION: Do not mix include-like and resource-like declarations for a
>   given class. If you declare or assign a class using both styles, it
>   can cause compilation failures.

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_classes.html#include-like-declarations

---

On the other hand, the roles and profiles documentation clearly encourages usage of resource-like declarations. Under the "Rules for profile classes" section, they state the following

> 3. Profiles own all the class parameters for their component classes. If the profile omits one, that means you definitely want the default
>      value; the component class shouldn’t use a value from Hiera data.

And the examples that follow above statement  are clearly using the resource-like syntax.

https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.2/r_n_p_full_example.html#the-rules-for-profile-classes

Answer (score 0):

Using profile classes for declarations will reduce the flexibility a lot, so I don't see any conflicts, from my perspective, I think what is being implied is that use resource-like declarations for passing parameters but use include-like declarations for better flexibility, especially when you want to setup software stacks for multiple servers. For example, this is what I've wrote for our Zabbix agents for all of the Linux servers :

```
class profile::base::zabbix_agent {

  package { 'zabbix_agent':
    ensure => 'installed',
    source => 'https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/4.4/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-4.4-1.el7.noarch.rpm',
    provider => 'rpm'
  }
}
```

There are more resource-like declarations, but I just put this one as an example. Then, I have an include-like declaration for my basic linux configuration, which is the same for all of our Linux servers in the infrastructure :

```
class role::base::linux {

  include profile::base::motd
  include profile::base::linux_defaults
  include profile::base::yum_config
  include profile::base::yum_cron
  include profile::base::clamav
  include profile::base::chrony
  include profile::base::crontab
  include profile::base::snmp
  include profile::base::zabbix_agent
  include profile::base::firewall
  include profile::base::repo_packages
  include profile::app::puppet_agent
}
```

Now each of the nodes can use a simple line to have all of the basic configurations in one place :

```
node 'dev-jenkins.mycompany.org' {

  include role::base::linux
  include profile::app::jenkins
}
```

I have written a resource-like declaration for each of the above classes, then I've created roles and profiles based on them. Now, if I want to update my zabbix agents, I just edit `profile::base::zabbix_agent` class and change the source. If I want to remove zabbix agents from the servers, I just change `ensure => 'installed'` from one file and it will be committed to all of the servers.
As you can see, using resource- and include-like declarations together can make the code very flexible and easy to change. You can make global, infrastructure-wide changes only with editing a couple of lines. Hope this has answered your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @aLuViAn. I get your point. However, in your case, Hiera is never used, and class parameters are inexistent for the profiles, so I guess it makes it much simpler.